# Text got cut of within the ListView for android-based app

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm using a ListView to store the data retrieve from my database but somehow the text inside the ListView has been cut off. I know that TextView could use the `setSingleLine`, `setEllipsize` but I have no idea what I could do for ListView nor why it was cut off. Not sure is it because of the submit button though.

I tried using the `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false)` which is used in Textview, but it seems useless.

my xml for the listview :

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:text="Submit"
    />
```

my code :

```
listView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dataList));
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

my ui display result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey vam i do this in my APPLICATION.

In Listview use this
`android:padding="10dp"`

May be you get solution.
if not getting then please tell me.
[Mehul Patel](http://mehulp89@gmail.com)

Comment: sorry, i'm working for a company, so i couldn't send you the file. the needed code is above.sorry.

Answer (score 0):

this is because each row has a specific height and your text view is not big enough to show that. For try to create a custom layout for row  and inflate it in getview method of Adapter

Comment: i have no idea how to create one. cant i just change the text size or the height itself ?